# Implicit differentiation with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, calculus

How can we derivate a implicit equation in Python 3?
Example `x^2+y^2=25` differentiation is: `dy/dx=-x/y`, when try this:

```
from sympy import *

init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')(x)

eq = x**2+y**2-25
sol = diff(eq, x)
print(sol)
```

But it shows:

```
2*x + 2*y(x)*Derivative(y(x), x)
```

How can get `-x/y`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SymPy has the function `idiff` which does what you want

```
In [2]: idiff(x**2+y**2-25, y, x)
Out[2]:
-x
───
 y
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the implicit function theorem which states that when two variables `x`, `y`, are related by the implicit equation `f(x, y) = 0`, then the derivative of `y` with respect to `x` is equal to `- (df/dx) / (df/dy)` (as long as the partial derivatives are continuous and `df/dy != 0`).

```
x, y = symbols('x, y')
f = x**2 + y**2 - 25
-diff(f,x)/diff(f,y)
```

> ```
> -x/y
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You have the differential equation, so you can rearrange it using solve:

```
solve(sol, diff(y, x, 1))
```